Rear 3/8 inches higher than front!! How will dipstick read
The rear of my two wheel drive truck is 3/8in higher than the front, how will the dipstick read the oil level??

The difference in height at the two points are spaced far enough apart that you are unlikely to detect any difference in level.
Most driveways are not level and you would not have difficulty with such circumstances, unless it's obviously seriously sloped.
Your truck isn't going to be sensitive to an oil level of even 3/8" at the dipstick, much less than 3/8" over the span of the wheelbase.
All is good.

I challenge the OP to find a hardstanding that is level to within 1 cm at all wheels anyway.
